# Grabbing the printer IP and printer name from a spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, parsing

I need to grab the printer IP address and printer name from a spreadsheet. How this spreadsheet looks:

```
Printer Model    Printer Name          Current IP       MAC     New IP
some printer     XRX0000AAF3230C       166.96.64.51     sad     127.0.1.1
example          NPIB36BA6             172.18.25.126    sad     255.255.255.0
```

How can I grab the IP address and the printer name, and insert them into a dict? I've been able to open and read the file using `xlrd` with the following code:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\Users\Documents\My Forms\Printers 3-14-2017.xlsx", encoding_override="cp1252")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("3rd Floor")
cols = sheet.ncols - 1
rows = sheet.nrows - 1
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < rows:
    curr_row += 1
    row = sheet.row(curr_row)
    print("Row: {}".format(curr_row))
    curr_cell = -1
    while curr_cell < cols:
        curr_cell += 1
        cell_type = sheet.cell_type(curr_row, curr_cell)
        cell_val = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_cell)
        try:
            print("Type: {}\nValue: {}\n".format(cell_type, cell_val))
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            print("Type: {}\nValue: {}\n".format(smart_str(cell_type), smart_str(cell_val)))
```

What I need to do is grab the printer name, and IP address, insert them into a dict and output that dict, how can I do this successfully and skip the other information, and the "new IP" section?

I thought about using regular expressions, this could work with the IP address, but there is not pattern in the printer name apart from printer types, such as Xerox printers start with `XRX`, HP printers start with `NP` or `HP`, etc.. Any help with this would be extremely appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why not use pandas?

Comment: @cricket_007 What is pandas?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: OR... You can fix your code to not use `while curr_cell < cols:` and instead only get the columns you really care about

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: What I need to do is grab the printer name, and IP address, insert them into a dic ...

```
my_dict['printer'] = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 2)
my_dict['IP address'] = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 3)
```

Columns are counted 1 based from left to right